# Custom Scaling Function for ListDensityPlot not working

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, scaling

I'm attempting to plot a data set with values that span multiple orders of magnitude, both positive and negative. I would like to use a logarithmic scaling to accurately capture this order of magnitude change, but needed to define a custom function to deal with the negative values. I've included the scaling function I use (`aL`) and its inverse (`aE`) as well as equivalent code

```
xR=Table[(Exp[0.06225 i]-1),{i,1,150}];
xt= Table[0.5 i,{i,1,500}];
Lt=Length[xt];LR=Length[xR];
Do[tdata[j] = Sort[Table[RandomReal[{-5, 5}]*10^RandomInteger[{5, 50}], {i, 1, LR}]], {j, 1, Lt}];
Pdat = Flatten[Table[{xt[[j]], xR[[z]], tdata[j][[z]]}, {j, 1, Lt}, {z, 1, LR}], 1];
aL = Sign[#] Log[1 + Abs[#]] &;
aE = Sign[#] (Exp[Abs[#]] - 1) &;
ListDensityPlot[Pdat, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", PlotLegends -> True, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log", {aL, aE}}]
```

The plot this creates doesn't look quite right, and the plot legend is a blank bar. I get the following error message:

> Coordinate {Indeterminate, Indeterminate} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The inverse function should only have output on the order of 10^50 since it's inverting the original scaling bringing things down from 10^50?

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course. I wasn't thinking properly.

Comment: I think I'm gonna have to pass on this question. This is as far as I got: By printing the function value given to `aE`, I noticed that while most are reals as they are supposed to be, some values passed to `aE` are lists of two reals. This could be a bug. I suspect that these have something to do with the problem. I tried to work around it by making `aE` take the first element from the list, when given a list, but I wasn't successful...